# How to do colspan in gridview row in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

How can I achieve the following format in gridview

[image]

Comment: what you have tried so far? Put your effort in you question that I have tried this ... and it's not working etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rowspan and colspan for ASP .net Gridview at runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19680848/rowspan-and-colspan-for-asp-net-gridview-at-runtime)

Comment: Hi please have a look at this link once any try if it matches your requirement. [Grid view with in another grid view(details grid)](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/05/gridview-with-in-gridview-or-nested.html)

Comment: i want to merge the gridview rows. no need nested gridview

Comment: ya i got the requirement, but what my idea is show groups in main gird and expand its rows in nested grid based on the data keys.

Comment: Merge row is my requirement.

Comment: i don't think that we can merge rows in grid view, we should use repeater to achieve this.

Comment: Here's the best solution: [colspan gridview rows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6936417/colspan-gridview-rows)

Comment: Link to possible solution: http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/05/gridview-with-in-gridview-or-nested.html

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, this is the solution that I found. this is in VB

```
Protected Sub GridV_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridV.RowDataBound
    If (e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow) Then
        'Here put the condition 
        If e.Row.Cells(3).Text = "0" Then 
            e.Row.Cells(1).ColumnSpan = 4
            e.Row.Cells(2).Visible = False
            e.Row.Cells(3).Visible = False
            e.Row.Cells(4).Visible = False
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

I hope this work for you.

Juan F. Esquerre